# how do i refer to the parent object value in child function in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have my object defined as follows:

```
function KoolTabs() {
    this.targetName = "";
    this.activeNode = 1;
this.init = function()
{
    this.targetName = arguments[0];
    this.activeNode = (arguments[1] || 1);
    this.setEle( this.activeNode );
    this.findNodes();
}
    this.findNodes = function()
    {
        for (i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
            myEle = document.links[i];
              x = document.links[i].href;
              if (x.indexOf("#" + this.targetName) >= 0) {
                myEle.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
              }
        }
    }
    this.onClick = function()
    {
        alert('Hello ' + this.activeNode);
    }
};
```

I am calling it like:

```
<script>
    var StockTabs = new KoolTabs;
    StockTabs.init('tabsStock', 1);
</script>
```

Now when i click on the object which has the method bing it says **"Hello undefined"**

how can i get the value of parent object activeNode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in that handler `this` refers to the clicked element, you can maintain a reference to the origin KoolTabs object though, like this:

```
function KoolTabs() {
  var self = this;
```

Then in your handler, use that reference, like this:

```
this.onClick = function()
{
    alert('Hello ' + self.activeNode);
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vnATB/). (I commented out the `setEle()` call, since that code wasn't included.)

Answer (score 1):

your `onClick` method is called in a different context when used as an event handler in this method- `this` no longer refers to your `KoolTabs` instance.

the easy work around is to create a closure with a self-referencing variable with a different name.

```
function KoolTabs() { 

    var self = this;

    this.targetName = ""; 
    this.activeNode = 1; 
    this.init = function() 
    { 
        this.targetName = arguments[0]; 
        this.activeNode = (arguments[1] || 1); 
        this.setEle( this.activeNode ); 
        this.findNodes(); 
    } 
    this.findNodes = function() 
    { 
        for (i=0;i<document.links.length;i++) { 
            myEle = document.links[i]; 
              x = document.links[i].href; 
              if (x.indexOf("#" + this.targetName) >= 0) { 
                myEle.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false); 
              } 
        } 
    } 
    this.onClick = function() 
    { 
        // "this" refers to a different object now. use the "self" 
        // variable to reference the KoolTabs instance.
        alert('Hello ' + self.activeNode); 
    } 
};
```

if you want to get fancy, you can look at jQuery's `bind` method to see how it generates a function call with the proper scope applied. it would be something like

```
$(myEle).click( this.onClick.bind(this) );
```

and when `onClick` fires, `this` would point to what you expect it to. you would not need to define the `self` reference.

Comment: The `.bind()` you're talking about it's from jQuery, it's in ECMAScript now :)

Comment: so which one is better? creating self refrence or passing as argument as per performance and memory?

Comment: @KoolKabin I don't know. I tend toward `self` because I don't use jquery that much, it's simple, and to my knowledge there is nothing "wrong" with it. If I already has jquery included I'd consider `bind` as it seems "cleaner" to me for some intangible reason.